# How to play animation for vertical movement in unity2d / check for vertical movement?

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

i have a character that is moving horizontally and vertically, the run animation is playing for the horizontal movement, however i can't get it to play when my character moves vertically.

I've tried a lot, this is my latest try

```
private void Awake()
    {
        rb = GetComponent<Rigidbody2D>();
        animator = GetComponent<Animator>();
    }
    
void Update()
    {
        // Inputs
   
        float vertical = Input.GetAxisRaw("Vertical");
        float moveDirection = Input.GetAxisRaw("Horizontal");
        
        animator.SetFloat("Speed", Mathf.Abs (moveDirection));

        Vector3 move = new Vector3(moveDirection,vertical * 0.6f,0);
        transform.position += move * 0.08f;

        if(rb.velocity.y < 0)
        {
            animator.SetFloat("Speed_v", Mathf.Abs (moveDirection));
        }
```

My understanding of C# and coding in general is still very limited, so help would be much appreciated!

Comment: Hey xMishax, Stack Overflow is more intended for help with specific issues you can name. Not to ask 'whats wrong with my code'. Keep that in mind for your next question :) . It's a bit difficult to solve your issue without knowing how your animator is set up. However, you seem to set `Speed_v` with `Mathf.Abs (moveDirection)`, where `moveDirection` is a variable that you set using horizontal input. Could the problem be that you are not moving horizontally and thus setting `Speed_v` to a value of `0`? Did you mean to set it with the input of the Vertical axis instead?

Comment: Hello, I am very sorry. This is my first question on here, I usually read a lot of other questions from other people to solve my problems, but this time I was helpless so I thought I could try searching for help. Maybe I'm too new to this. I changed the Input but it's no use :/ I will try searching for a different method to solve this. Thanks for the comment!

Comment: That's quite alright, everyone starts somewhere :) it might be helpful to update your post with information about your Animator component and what you expect to happen. See [this page](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) for help on writing your questions!

Answer (score 0):

You should try playing animations using Animator Boolean values. Animation Boolean values provide a way to transition between animation states.

Normally the way a standard animator is set up is to have an "Idle" state that plays an idle animation on loop while your avatar is not moving. On top of the "Idle" state you will need a "Walk"/ "Run" state. You can add transitions between these two states so the animations can blend properly.

You can see how to set up transitions here: https://docs.unity3d.com/Manual/class-Transition.html

In your specific case, you will need at least three states: "Idle", "Walk-Horizontal" and "Walk-Vertical". In addition to these states you will need two bool values: "Is-Walking-Horizontally" and "Is-Walking-Vertically". You need to set their values via code, the same way you set your "Speed" value in your example.